# Java 8 Date and Time API - parse yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I'm trying to parse date in ISO8601 format:

*yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ*

Am I correct that it is not possible to parse it with any of the default formats defined in **java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter**?

For example ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME will parse only:

*yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ*

Samples:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
2015-04-29T10:15:00.500+0000

yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ
2015-04-29T10:15:00.500+00:00
```

BTW:I know I can define my own formatter that is not the issue. Just wanted to ensure that I'm not missing something as the *ISODateTimeFormat* of **Joda** is able to parse both:

```
 org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
 DateTime dateTime = dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime("2015-04-29T10:15:00.500+0000");
```

Comment: You can set your own DateFormatter

Comment: The documentation isn't clear about the difference between Z and ZZ - could you give some sample text that you're trying to parse that doesn't parse with ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME? (It looks like it's more like ZZZZZ than ZZ, as it includes a colon.)

Comment: Turns out defining a java.time formatter that can parse both isn't straightforward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should never be bothered by those annoying date-format.

There has an new library [dateparser](https://github.com/sisyphsu/dateparser).

It can recognize any **String** automatically, and parse it into **Date**, **Calendar**, **LocalDateTime**, **OffsetDateTime** correctly.

With it, you don't have to prepare any appropriate patterns like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` or `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ`:

```
Date date = DateParserUtils.parseDate("2015-04-29T10:15:00.500+0000");
Calendar calendar = DateParserUtils.parseCalendar("2015-04-29T10:15:00.500Z");
LocalDateTime dateTime = DateParserUtils.parseDateTime("2015-04-29 10:15:00.500 +00:00");
```

All works fine, please enjoy it.

Comment: That library worked like a charm after a lot of struggle.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure this is your expected answer.

**Method 1**

Parse using Instant

```
Instant.parse("2015-06-28T10:13:14.743Z");
```

**Method 2**

The given input format is equivalent to ISO_DATE_TIME format 
after removing 'Z' from the given pattern yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ

Then we can parse it using ISO_DATE_TIME

```
 text = "2015-06-28T10:13:14.743"
 LocalDateTime.parse(text,DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
```

Answer (score 4):

You are correct in that this does not appear to match any of the default formats, so you would need to build your format with a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

Comment: As I sad, I know I can define my own format that is able to parse yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ that isn't the issue here. I want a format that is able to parse both "Z" and "ZZ", ideally default one that is supplied in java.time.format.* somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Joda uses ISO8601 formats for default ISODateTimeFormat. So based on the document http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime, Joda would not be able to parse your format.

Comment: You can try for yourself Joda is able to parse it.

Comment: See my answer, of course Joda / java.util.time can create a DateTimeFormatter that is able to parse the given format.